# c++ macros with memory?

Tags: c++, macros

Is it possible to define macros

```
write_foo(A);
and
read_foo();
```

so that:

```
WRITE_FOO(hello);

code_block_1;

READ_FOO();

code_block_2;

READ_FOO();

WRITE_FOO(world);

code_block_3;

READ_FOO();

code_block_4;

READ_FOO();
```

expands into:

```
code_block_1;
hello;
code_block_2;
hello;

code_boock_3;
world;
code_block_4;
world;
```

?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably, using #pragma push/pop and redefining the a 'DEFINE'. I dont know C/C++, to help you out more.

Comment: Whenever someone does something complex with a MACRO, I gotta ask "why?".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macros cannot redefine other macros, but you can do it manually.

```
#define FOO hello

FOO // expands to hello

#undef FOO
#define FOO world

FOO // expands to world

#undef FOO
#define FOO blah

FOO // expands to blah
```

Unfortunately, the `#define` + `#undef` combination cannot be encapsulated in any other structure that I am aware of.

Comment: But that's ok as long as it `#undef` s READ_FOO.

Comment: Guess what! [Somebody tried this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526096/c-macro-with-memory) and it doesn't work!

Comment: @Shahbaz: Bah, there's egg on my face — you're right, it doesn't work. I understand the preprocessor better now than I did when I posted this, and I don't think there's any way to fix this or really answer the question. The `#undef` needs to occur after the uses of `READ_FOO` and before the `#define` which resets the parameter. Headers cannot simplify the obvious, straightforward solution simply using `#define` and `#undef` as they were originally intended.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible since macro should not contain preprocessor directives.

Answer (score 3):

Not what you are actually asking for, but if `WRITE_FOO` was a definition you could get something similar (without context I will just reuse the names, even if they are not so clear on the intent):

```
#define READ_FOO() WRITE_FOO

#define WRITE_FOO hello
code...[1]
READ_FOO();
code...[2]
#define WRITE_ROO world
code...[3]
READ_FOO();

// will expand to:
code...[1]
hello;
code...[2]
code...[3]
world;
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the sweet spot for tools like [Cog](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/cog/) that approach the problem of code generation from an intuitive programming approach using python. This is what would look like your code using it

```
/*[[[cog
# definitions ----
import cog
Foo = ''
def WriteFoo( value ):
    Foo = value

def ReadFoo():
    cog.outl(' %s; ' % Foo)

# generation ---
WriteFoo( 'hello' )
]]]*/
//[[[end]]]

some_code_block;

/*[[[cog 
ReadFoo() ]]]*/
hello;
//[[[end]]]

some_other_blocK;

/*[[[cog 
WriteFoo( 'world')
ReadFoo() ]]]*/
world;
//[[[end]]]


last_block;
```