# Macros in macros

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to put a macro in a macro in c++?

Something like:

```
#define Something\
#ifdef SomethingElse\ //do stuff \
#endif\
```

I tried and it didn't work so my guess is it doesn't work, unless there's some sort of syntax that can fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, but you can simply refactor this by pulling the `#ifdef` out as the toplevel, and using two different `#define Something ...` versions for the true and false branches of the `#ifdef`.

Answer (score 22):

Macros, yes. Preprocessor directives, which are what you posted, no

Answer (score 4):

You can't use preprocessor directives in macros, but if we want to check if `SomethingElse` is defined and call a different macro, you could accomplish it like this(requires a c99 preprocessor and Boost.Preprocessor library):

```
#define PP_CHECK_N(x, n, ...) n
#define PP_CHECK(...) PP_CHECK_N(__VA_ARGS__, 0,)

//If we define SomethingElse, it has to be define like this
#define SomethingElse ~, 1,

#define Something \
BOOST_PP_IF(PP_CHECK(SomethingElse), MACRO1, MACRO2)
```

If `SomethingElse` is defined it will call `MACRO1`, otherwise it will call `MACRO2`. For this to work, `SomethingElse` has to be defined like this:

```
#define SomethingElse ~, 1,
```

By the way, this won't work in Visual Studio, because of a bug in their compiler, there is a workaround here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/380090/variadic-macro-replacement

Answer (score 2):

No. I answered this in [c++ macros with memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506167/c-macros-with-memory)

If you want to inspect or alter the preprocessing environment, in other words to define a preprocessing subroutine rather than a string-replacement macro, you need to use a header, although the legitimate reasons for doing so are few and far between.