# Macro Redefinition

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I am trying to create a "global variable" in the pre-processor that can be incremented.

For example, I have defined `abc` as `1`. Can I redefine it into 2 next time (i got a redefinition error when i do this)? Do I need to first use `undef`? But
I got compile error when using `undef`.

What is the proper way of doing something like this?

```
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o

error: use of undeclared identifier 'BOOST_PP_INC_abc'

    std::cout << temp << endl;

note: instantiated from:

    #define temp BOOST_PP_INC(abc)

note: instantiated from:

    #define BOOST_PP_INC(x) BOOST_PP_INC_I(x)
note: instantiated from:

    #define BOOST_PP_INC_I(x) BOOST_PP_INC_ ## x

<scratch space>:150:1: note: instantiated from: BOOST_PP_INC_abc

1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/preprocessor/slot/counter.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/add.hpp>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;

    #define abc 1
    #define temp BOOST_PP_INC(abc)
    #undef abc

    std::cout << temp << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this? There's probably a better way than macro abuse.

Comment: I am trying to keep track of the number abc. And then use it in the compile time.

Comment: @NegativeZero, use cog: http://nedbatchelder.com/code/cog/ lot cleaner to work with that macro mess. Check this answer to see an example that might be relevant to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506167/c-macros-with-memory/9455483#9455483

Comment: hi Lurscher, your link to the another stack overflow post is really helpful. I think that's something I wanted to do. It looks like i can change the value with the help of another header file. Let me investigate a little further.

Comment: hmm... I am trying the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506167/c-macros-with-memory/9455483#9455483. But it's not compiling for me

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the value of preprocessor macros inside the preprocessor I'm afraid. Perhaps you should rethink this in terms of the underlying goal you are trying to accomplish? You haven't stated what the underlying purpose to incrementing a preprocessor value would be.