# C++ Macro with Memory

Tags: c++, boost, c-preprocessor

This is originally posted as an answer to [c++ macros with memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506167/c-macros-with-memory/9455483#9455483)

But somehow I am not able to get this compiled. I might be missing something here. (I have a feeling that this is something C++ can do)

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const char * hello = "hello";
const char * world = "world";

#define VAR

#define MEMORIZE world
#include "memorize.h"
#define MEMORIZE hello
#include "memorize.h"

int main() {
    cout << VAR << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

memorize.h

```
#undef VAR
#ifndef MEMORIZE
    # error "No Argument to memorize.h"
#endif
#define VAR MEMORIZE
#undef MEMORIZE
```

The compile error that I am getting is this:

```
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o
error: use of undeclared identifier 'MEMORIZE'
    cout << VAR << endl;
            ^
note: instantiated from:
#define VAR MEMORIZE
            ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I really want to get this memory thing to work in preprocessing phase. Can someone help? I think `BOOST_PP_COUNTER` in `1.49` also uses this technique but i couldn't figure out how.

Comment: I hope this is for some kind of masochistic amusement rather than for production code. :-D

Comment: well, currently it's not compiling...
even if I want to put it in a broader use, i can't :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using only a single `VAR` value (the last one) because it can take only one value. If you want to mean different things by `VAR` depending on the context, you need to have source statements after each include.

```
#define xstr(a) str(a)
#define str(a) #a
int main() {
#define MEMORIZE world
#include "memorize.h"
      cout << VAR << endl;
#undef MEMORIZE
#define MEMORIZE hello
#include "memorize.h"
      cout << VAR << endl;
          return 0;
}
```

memorize.h:

```
#undef VAR
#ifndef MEMORIZE
    # error "No Argument to memorize.h"
#endif
#define VAR xstr(MEMORIZE)
```

Comment: I don't think what I intended is possible. I'll accept your answer since it's very educational.

Answer (score 0):

You are are setting the `VAR` macro to the token `MEMORIZE`, which you are promptly undefining. The line:

```
cout << VAR << endl;
```

ends up as:

```
cout << MEMORIZE << endl;
```

and since `MEMORIZE` is undeclared, you get the error. It thinks `MEMORIZE` is a variable name.

Comment: Are you suggesting this is not something can be done? I am just wondering how did BOOST_PP_COUNTER works? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html

Comment: If it can be done, I have no idea how. A better, simpler, and more standard solution is to define a macro to have a certain value before using it, and you can 'redefine' it anywhere you please.

Comment: I looked at the boost source, and (from a possibly inaccurate skim of the code) it looks like they use `if (counter == 0) { counter = 1 } else if (counter == 1) { counter = 2 } ...` style code, except with digit manipulation to enable multidigit numbers with sub-exponential code size. Somewhere there is a programmer with brain damage.

Comment: i think it's probably not possible now with just one variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `#undef MEMORIZE` line -- take it out of memorize.h and put it right before `#define MEMORIZE` everywhere that appears.